# Convert Varchar2 24h time to 12h format SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `Varchar2` column in a table that contains a time like `'13:24:02'`. I want to convert the value into 12h format with am/pm eg. `01:24:02 PM`

Is there any way to do it? Tried `to_char` and `to_date` but isn't giving me the result that I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a date and then back to a string in the correct format:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(your_column, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH12:MI:SS AM')
         AS formatted_time
FROM   your_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (your_column) AS
SELECT '13:24:02' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FORMATTED_TIME |
> | --- |
> | 01:24:02 PM |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f47f687f32973ee01bcd4844bbb2d1ab)*